# Send video from gallery to Firebase server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am able to attach an image from gallery and send it to firebase. But I want to upload video from gallery to firebase. I have read documents for firebase but I could not find anything.

So has anyone done this before? Advanced help would be appreciated !

**Code:**

Here while select video from gallery and on activity result

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
            StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                    .setContentType("video/mpeg")
                    .build();
            if (selectedVideoUri == null) {
                Log.e("selected video path", "null");
                finish();
            } else {
                Log.v("selectedVideoPath", selectedVideoUri.toString());
                if (selectedVideoUri != null) {
                    StorageReference videoGalleryRef = storageRefVideo.child(selectedVideoUri + "_video");
                    sendFileFirebaseVideo(videoGalleryRef, selectedVideoUri, metadata);
                }
            }
        }

 private void sendFileFirebaseVideo(StorageReference storageReference, final Uri file, final StorageMetadata metadata) {
    if (storageReference != null) {
        final String name = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();
        StorageReference videoGalleryRef = storageReference.child(name + "_video");
        UploadTask uploadTask = videoGalleryRef.putFile(file, metadata);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure sendFileFirebase " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess sendFileFirebase");
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                FileModel fileModel = new FileModel("video", downloadUrl.toString(), name, "");
                ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(userModel, "", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() + "", fileModel);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE).push().setValue(chatModel);
            }
        });
    } else {
    }

}
```

Comment: Uploading a file to Firebase Storage is covered in the Firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files. If you're having trouble with it, share the [minimal code that reproduces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please check my edit. What problem may be in my code?

Comment: Thanks for that. What's the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Problem that i can't see video in my screen. It shows only black square. Also I have tried to upload video from firebase storage server then it shows _Error uploading Slack for iOS Upload.mp4: An unexpected server error occurred.
CANCEL
RETRY_

Comment: Did you try downloading the video out of the Firebase Storage console and playing it? If it doesn't play that way, the video likely got corrupted while uploading and you know to focus on that code. If it plays fine when downloaded from the console, the problem is in the code that downloads/plays it. Eliminating sections of your code like this is the key to debugging any app.

Comment: Yes while i m uploading video from my app and check and download that video then it is playing

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create instance of StorageReference
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
final StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child("FolderToCreate").child("NameYoWantToAdd");
// add File/URI
photoRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(filename))
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Upload succeeded
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Success...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
              // Upload failed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(
        new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //calculating progress percentage
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                //displaying percentage in progress dialog
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This helped me a lot!